# Remove duplicate array from the end

Tags: php, arrays

I am having data that I can arrange into an arrays of two. as shown below:

```
$array1 = array(30,17,12,6,89,23,45,45,45);  
$array2 = array(30,17,12,6,89,23,45,45,45,45);
```

if the last element of `$array` is the same as the last element of `$array2`, I would like to remove all the identical elements but from the last. Therefore in this case I want `$array1` to be:

```
$array1 = array(30,17,12,6,89,23)
```

But if the last element if `$array1` is not similar to `$array2` i should get all elements in `$array1`. i.e

```
$array1 = array(30,17,12,6,89,23,45,45,45);  
$array2 = array(30,17,12,6,89,23,45,45,45,47);
```

It should return

```
$array1 = array(30,17,12,6,89,23,45,45,45);
```

Can someone give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = array(30,17,12,6,89,23,45,45,45);
$array2 = array(30,17,12,6,89,23,45,45,45,45);
if(end($array1) == end($array2)) {
    $number = end($array1);
    while(end($array1) == $number) array_pop($array1);
    while(end($array2) == $number) array_pop($array2);
}
var_dump($array1);
```

Comment: Don't you mean array_pop(); ?

Comment: This loop will execute 3 times for this array. If the array becomes larger, then this might *not* be very efficient.

Comment: also, you're assuming the identical values all appear at the end of the array

Comment: and this is what he wanted to remove identical values from end of array. To remove duplicates from both we could just use array_diff()

Comment: Yes it should not remove any other duplicate as long as it does not appear at the end of the array.

Comment: Ok now I'm not really sure what did you want to achieve:
a) if last element of a1 equals a2 we remove only last elements and check again last elements?
b) if last element of a1 equals a2 we remove all occurences of last element from end of array